# Assigning percentages to different causes

Tags: regression, model, causality, philosophical

There was recently a celebrated spat between Cathy Newman, one of the main presenters of Channel 4 News in the UK, and Jordan Peterson, a well-known academic and clinical psychologist, on the causes of the gender pay gap. You can listen to it on YouTube, where it has been viewed over 9 million times. Peterson says that "statistics show" that only x% of the gender pay gap is due to prejudice against women. The exact value of x is not relevant to my question.

I recently read a discussion about whether human intelligence is inherited or acquired, with the conclusion that it's 50% nature and 50% nurture.

What would it mean, if anything, to say *"The taste of a cake is 10% due to the proportion of flour to butter and 20% due to the freshness of the eggs."*

My question is *When is it sensible to assign percentages to the causes of some phenomenon?* What kinds of statistical or scientific model are being assumed and what kinds of evidence could be adduced that such a model is appropriate? This is a big topic, so I would welcome pointers to clearly written articles on the subject, and also pointers to relevant books.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is usually some form of [effect size](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Effect_size).

For a notable and commonly used example, you may perform an [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) and calculate $\eta^2$ ("eta squared") which is described [here](https://stardock.cs.virginia.edu/empirical/resources/Brown28.pdf) as

> "the proportion of variance associated with or accounted for
>   by each of the main effects, interactions, and error in an ANOVA study"

Which is quite literally a percentage assigned to causes of some phenomena.